# can't find web element in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

Today i try find web element and count in mercedes web site,

But i cant find the element, i use intellij ide and thats my code.

```
System.setProperty("web.driver.chromedriver", "/Users/username/Desktop/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));

driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(500, SECONDS);

driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();


driver.get("https://www.mercedes-benz.de/passengercars/buy/new-car/search-results.html/?emhvehicleAssortment=new-passenger-cars&emhsort=name-asc");


Thread.sleep(10000);

WebElement car = driver.findElement(By.className("dcp-cars-srp-results__tile"));

car.getSize();

System.out.println(car.getSize());
```

This element count doesn't show up when I inspect and call it with control + f.

//*[class="dcp-cars-srp-results__tile"]

Can you help me?

System.out.println(car.getSize());

Comment: _We currently do not have any vehicle in stock that suits your preference.
If you wish, you can update your preferences or contact our authorized agency._

Comment: it looks like you have an iframe in your page, make sure you handle the iframe first and then try to find the web element you need. try this link https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html

Comment: Hi @MuratIshen i try the swatich iframe but it doesnt work .. i try this code driver.switchTo().frame("dcp-cars-srp-results__tile"); and i get this exception "No frame element found by name or id dcp-cars-srp-results__tile" 
How can i handle this?

Comment: are you sure you have that element  exists? can you show us the screenshot of the element you are trying to find? what is the element id and what is the iframe id?

Comment: dcp-cars-srp-results__tile element is different, iframe is two different elements in the page

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/8rboodf.png @MuratIshen that's screen shot, when i search this element , i dont get a result , and try this web site, mercedes german web site same our country https://www.mercedes-benz.de/passengercars/buy/new-car/search-results.html/?emhvehicleAssortment=new-passenger-cars&emhsort=name-asc